# When working with two databases, how to not fetch the records in the second run?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

In my spring batch job using spring-boot I am using two different databases as source and destination.

At first I fetch records from the source database. Then I write to the destination database.

How and where can I update a field in the source database, so that those records will not be fetched in the second run?

I'm using JPA-Hibernate and ItemReader/processor/Writer.

Comment: Hi @shawn and welcome to stackoverflow! I reformatted and rephrased title and body of your question. I still did not fully understand the question, but I hope I improved it a bit. Could you please check, that it still represents your intention? Please amend your question with examples and details to help us understand it.

Comment: Thanks for Rephrasing @Slartidan, right now we configured a job that is fetching limited records from one database and we process them and write/insert to an other database and the job is getting completed successfully. but the main aim of this batch is, if there are still records left in the source database then a second run has to happen and fetch the un-processed records from first run and process the records and write to destination database until all the records are processed, which I'm trying to update a field in source-DB so not to fetch those again in later run!

Comment: Query query1 = entityManager.createNativeQuery("UPDATE EVENT_BAT p set p.NTFCN_SEND_DT=trunc(sysdate) where p.USER_TYPE_CD = 'primary' and p.ACCT_ID ='8114494'");
int updatedRows = query1.executeUpdate();
entityManager.flush();
entityManager.close();

For the above to update the field, in the console it is showing as 'updatedRows:1' but in the database it is not Reflecting(Not sure it is really Updating)